# Is there a way to check Youtube archived live stream chat?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have try the Youtube data API for the `Videos` and `LiveChatMessages` endpoints, but I found that the `liveBroadcastContent` is get a `none` value for every old live stream `Videos` call, which is required for the `LiveChatMessages` call. Anyone know how to achieve that?

Ref. API page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide such a basic feature.

However I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/db43f57a7399546a20cae19b56b0b4148fe6d0d0#diff-95e2f8395ed232c4b2453600a9d71a97ce756c3ee01fcff1fefdcf661df99da2) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/liveChats?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID&time=0 you will get the first live stream chat messages.
Especially may interest you:

- Message: `item["message"]["runs"][0]["text"]` (example: `Hello`)
- Author channel id: `item["authorExternalChannelId"]` (example: `UCwXmFws4KX57nLQ1Wivf1uQ`)
- Time relative to the livestream: `item["timestampText"]["simpleText"]` (example: `3:41:39`)
- Absolute time: `item["timestampUsec"]` (example: `1620493869868368`)

Then to get the following live stream chat messages, just pass as `time` in the above URL the last chat message retrieved in milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time knowing this, the ultimate goal that I want to achieve is to search what did a user said in different live stream. I have seen some sites that have monetarizing live chat before so I though there is an easy solution on the youtube API. Anyway, I will definitely check out the open-source Youutbe operational API.

Comment: Got some updates, I found a extension called chat_downloader which did exactly what I want, I have tried use it to extract over a million chats in 1 file without fails. https://github.com/xenova/chat-downloader

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried with
https://yt.lemnoslife.com/lives?part=snippet&id=HcTqj30dJYM&time=0 and got
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid part snippet"
  }

Comment: [@hypers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4684507/hypers) Indeed my bad I have written the incorrect endpoint URL, I corrected it, so this URL works: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/liveChats?part=snippet&id=HcTqj30dJYM&time=0